# Looking to generate new rows for roles missing in initial query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a current set of data that looks like the following:

Table Name: Project_EffectiveDating

| ProjectCode | RoleCode | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a1 | A | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | B | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | C | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | D | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | E | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | A | 2/1/2020 |

| ProjectCode | RoleCode | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a1 | A | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | B | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | C | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | D | 1/1/2020 |
| 1a1 | E | 1/1/2020 |
| ***1a1*** | ***A*** | ***2/1/2020*** |
| ***1a1*** | ***B*** | ***2/1/2020*** |
| ***1a1*** | ***C*** | ***2/1/2020*** |
| ***1a1*** | ***D*** | ***2/1/2020*** |
| ***1a1*** | ***E*** | ***2/1/2020*** |

Where the top table is existing data and the bottom table is the desired output.

I have been trying to join the table on itself with the following:

```
select 
  dbd.projectcode
, dbd.role
, dbd.effectivedate
from Project_EffectiveDating as dbd 
left join Project_EffectiveDating as dad 
     on dad.projectcode = dbd.projectcode 
     and dbd.rolecode <> dad.rolecode
```

but obviously this is not working. I was thinking about doing a union statement using a WHERE NOT IN()
but am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a Cartesian product between pairs of `ProjectCode`/`RoleCode` and `EffectiveDate`:

```
select *
from (select distinct ProjectCode, RoleCode
      from Project_EffectiveDating
     ) pr cross join
     (select distinct EffectiveDate
      from Project_EffectiveDating
     ) e;
```

If you want to add in the rows that don't exist:

```
insert into Project_EffectiveDating (ProjectCode, RoleCode, EffectiveDate)
    select pr.ProjectCode, pr.RoleCode, e.EffectiveDate
    from (select distinct ProjectCode, RoleCode
          from Project_EffectiveDating
         ) pr cross join
         (select distinct EffectiveDate
          from Project_EffectiveDating
         ) e left join
         Project_EffectiveDating ped
         on ped.ProjectCode = pr.ProjectCode and
            ped.RoleCode = pr.RoleCode and
            ped.EffectiveDate = pr.EffectiveDate
    where ped.ProjectCode is null;
```

Comment: Awesome...this worked like a charm! Thank you so much.